# XSLT - How to remove certain words and join the rest using "OR"

Tags: string, xslt-2.0

I have a string such as this

```
Advances in the field of radiotherapy
```

I want the common stop words such as "in", "the", "of" etc. removed from the string and join the resultant string with an "OR". So, it will look like

```
Advances OR field OR radiotherapy
```

The list of stop words can grow, so I don't want to use a `replace()` function to remove the stop words. Is there a way that I can keep a list of all the stop words and use that list to process strings?

I can use a XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a gobal parameter with your stop words e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="stop-words" select="'in', 'the', 'of'"/>
```

and then use `analyze-string` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="stop-words" select="'in', 'the', 'of'"/>

<xsl:param name="rep" select="'OR'"/>

<xsl:variable name="regex" 
  select="concat('(^|\W)(', string-join($stop-words, '|'), ')', '(\W(', string-join($stop-words, '|'), '))*($|\W)')"/>

<xsl:template match="@* |  node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" priority="5">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$regex}">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(1), $rep, regex-group(5))"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the input being

```
<text>Advances in the field of radiotherapy</text>
```

the output with Saxon 9.5 is

```
<text>Advances OR field OR radiotherapy</text>
```

Based on your comment I think you simply want

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="mf">

<xsl:param name="stop-words" select="'in', 'the', 'of'"/>

<xsl:param name="rep" select="' OR '"/>

<xsl:variable name="regex" 
  select="concat('(^|\W)(', string-join($stop-words, '|'), ')', '(\W(', string-join($stop-words, '|'), '))*($|\W)')"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:process">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="replace(replace($input, $regex, '$1$5'), '\s+', $rep)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@* |  node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]" priority="5">
  <xsl:value-of select="mf:process(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<root>
<text>Advances in the field of radiotherapy</text>
<text>Advances made in the field of radiotherapy</text>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
<text>Advances OR field OR radiotherapy</text>
<text>Advances OR made OR field OR radiotherapy</text>
</root>
```

It might even be possible to simplify the pattern more, I will leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I have the string in a variable, so I suppose I can call the template containing analyze-string with the string as parameter, say with name 'text', and replace all the . with $text ?

Comment: Yes, write a named template or function with a parameter of type string (e.g. `<xsl:param name="input"/>`) and then inside of the template or function use `<xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$regex}">` instead of `<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$regex}">`. The `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` should not be changed however as it is inside of the analyze-string and outputs the value of anything not matched by the pattern.

Comment: Sorry, looks like the question was not very clear. I don't want to replace the stop words with "OR". I want to remove the stop words, and then insert the "OR" wherever there is a white space. The current solution replaces the stop words with "OR". It doesn't work for - `Advances made in the field of radiotherapy`, which should transform to - `Advances OR made OR field OR radiotherapy` instead of `Advances made OR field OR radiotherapy`. Could you please modify the solution?